# How to execute FQL/PHP Query from codes?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, status

In `Graph API Explorer` at `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer`, and in the `FQL Query` panel, i can run something like following query:

```
SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = '67060XXXX'
```

It is for pulling the `statuses` of a friend, with his/her `uid`. So it shows/returns the `statuses` of that person. So in that [Facebook Developer FQL Panel](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20status%20WHERE%20uid=%2767060XXXX%27), it is even returning something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "This is my status message. Xxxxxxxxxxxx bla bla bla xx x x x x x xxx"
    },
    {
      "message": "xx x x x  xxxxxxxxxx x x x x xxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "message": "nananananananananana"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Showing the "Status Messages" of my friend.**
In other word, i got this result **by running the FQL Query from**:

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20status%20WHERE%20uid='67060XXXX'](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20status%20WHERE%20uid=%2767060XXXX%27)

- **But how can i execute that query from my own codes?**

In my `PHP Codes`, used like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '4492848XXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'ae142d2cbf984a9XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
));
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$fql = "SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = '67060XXXX'";
$result = $facebook->api(array(
             'method'       => 'fql.query',
             'access_token' => $access_token, //tried either with/without this
             'query'        => $fql,
          ));
print_r($result);
```

It doesn't work :( Just giving the blank result, like: `Array ( )`

- Whats the difference? Or what am i missing?

*Note: I have already logged in with `appId & secret` etc, like: `$user = $facebook->getUser();` and it is fine already. Also i checked everything i can see in the `Get Access Token` box, and when it prompted to me, i accepted.*

[image]

Comment: check your access token permissions (friends_status)

Comment: Hi Hemc, please see my added image :S

Comment: Is the uid yours ? If yes then try with `me()` to see if you get any result or not. Your code seems to be fine.

Comment: You did't get my point. Apply same permission when user login to your app or authorize your app.

Comment: Hi @AnveshSaxena and @Hemc, if i even put uid `me()`, it still shows blank `Array()`. What i've actually done is, as this is my first FB App, i went to FB Developer Site and asked for NEW WEB/PHP APP. Then i just got a new app and i used the PHP SDK in my code `localhost`. Then when i pressed, `Get Access Token`, it pop-up a prompt and i just press agree. That's all... The `App` is still not even published (or) using by no one but myself testing in local. Am i missing some step, please? ---->

Comment: ... But this fb `given query in sdk sample`, is working and returning me the dataset: `SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, email FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Comment: This is happening most probably because you are using **App Access Token**. I just checked your code one more time. And I think you are having the trouble at this point, either generate the Access Token from Graph Explorer and put it in `$accessToken` or implement Login. Also, you might have to implement Login flow as the token have short (2hrs) validity.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena Hi thanks much for your help. But i have generated Access Token from Graph Explorer one more time, but no affect yet. For the `Login`, actually the Facebook PHP SDK Example code already included the `Login` there. I just didn't mention in the code portion above. It is like: `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();` Then use it in the `<a href`. Is it? So any more idea please :(

Comment: @4lvin do you have `read_stream` required to query status table?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena since i'm very new FB developer, i'm sorry for my questions. Then as far as i know, i checked every ticks on every boxes i can see, as in the above screen, on all the other tabs as well. Is it what you mean "read_stream" permission, please?

Comment: @4lvin , its a permission listed on Extended Permissions section of the image you have added, just check if it is checked or not